# How to Remove Leading and Trailing spaces in COBOL

Tags: cobol

```
05 WS-IN-MRKT-TYPE    PIC X(20).
05 WS-OUT-MRKT-TYPE   PIC X(20).
Procedure Divison
Move Function Trim(WS-IN-MRKT-TYPE) TO WS-OUT-MRKT-TYPE
Move WS-OUT-MRKT-TYPE to OUTPUT File.
```

Here Trim function is not working but if I am using Trim Function with display statement then it is working properly But I need to move the trim field to output file.
Display function trim(WS-IN-MRKT-TYPE)

Comment: Define 'not working'. What is happening instead?

Comment: The WS-OUT-MRKT-TYPE has a PICTURE of X(20).  Any character string you move to that field will be padded with trailing spaces.

Comment: If those spaces are seen in the output file then you likely would want to adjust it to be "LINE SEQUENTIAL" (=auto-trim right spaces with most COBOL implementors, you have not specified which one you use)